# Java Threads, Blocking I/O, and Scheduling

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, blocking

*The Scenario below is simplified*

Server is a 4 Core Intel (no hyperthreading) Linux Server, Java 11 Server 64 VM. We have a ThreadPoolExecutor with a maxSize of 15 Threads.

One method using the Executor submits 4 Callables that do long running database calls, another method uses the Executor to submit 10 more that do very fast calculations.  The first 4 Threads get CPU time and then Block awaiting queries to return.  My question is two fold - are the DB calls similar to Blocking I/O and when new Callables are submitted and assigned threads will those threads start running while the other threads are waiting on the DB calls to return, or will they be queued?  I know there are many variables I am not covering here, point them out if they are pertinent, but I think the base question is pretty clear.

Comment: Assuming “DB calls” means JDBC method calls, yes, they all behave as blocking calls.  If your thread pool has 15 threads, and only 4 threads are occupied with long-running tasks, it’s safe to assume any additional shorter tasks will not be held up.

Comment: @VGR On a 4 core box?

Comment: @BasilBourque I’m not certain, but I believe the JVM can create artificial (“virtual”) threads to exceed the hardware limit.  The most recent [Thread javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) talks about this.

Comment: @VGR Virtual threads are a preview feature, ***not* enabled by default**. Part of the [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) feature set being incubated and previewed through Java 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are the DB calls similar to Blocking I/O

Yes, calls involving [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) block, thereby pausing the host [OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) thread underlying a Java [thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)). At least currently, in Java 11, and in Java 17 & 20.

This fact may change if [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) succeeds.

> when new Callables are submitted and assigned threads will those threads start running while the other threads are waiting on the DB calls to return, or will they be queued?

If all of the threads in the thread pool backing your executor service are blocked, or are otherwise busy/occupied, pending tasks are queued as are any more submitted tasks. This queueing is the main job of an executor service.

Again, *Project Loom* with its [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/436) (technically, [fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science))) aims to alter this situation.

> Server is a 4 Core Intel (no hyperthreading) … a maxSize of 15 Threads

Do you suspect your shorter simply calls are piling up behind your long blocking database calls that hog all the threads? Like some small fast commuter cars stuck behind a convoy of big slow [semi-trailer trucks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-trailer_truck) on a highway?

If so, consider instantiating *two* [executor services](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

- Dedicate one executor service to the long-blocking database calls (the big slow semi-trailer trucks).
- Dedicate the other executor service as an “express lane” for all the other shorter simpler calls (the small fast commuter cars).

---

Let me stress that future readers of this Answer should check for updates on the progress of *Project Loom* after [Java 20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_20). The calculus of how to manage threading will change dramatically.